# How can I remotely rebase master from a branch?

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to merge a branch into master, but our private Gitlab installation complains that there are merge conflicts. There isn't, so I want to force merge and overwrite the master branch. Is that possible?

Here's my workflow :

1. I'm currently the sole developer on this project
2. I make all changes to the `dev` branch
3. When I `commit` and `push`, it is always to the `dev` branch.
4. Once these changes are ready to be deployed, I create a pull request to `master` (remote only)
5. The `master` branch cannot be directly pushed to
6. Once the merge is done, I deploy the app from a server (i.e. `git pull origin master`)

I have done this, but now there are undreds of conflicts. I want to ignore them as the `dev` branch is what should be pushed to `master`. In other words, wasting time "resolving" all these "conflicts" would result to the same as if I would simply force merge `dev` into `master`. However, git won't allow this.

How can I override this and force `master` to take all the changes from `dev`?

Comment: _"There isn't"_ - but there must be? Double-check the command it's trying to use and do that locally

Comment: Git is not lying, if there is a conflict you have a conflict.

Comment: Merge your remote master into your local dev, resolve conflicts, then make a PR to master

Comment: Why are you so sure there are no merge conflicts? Are you sure your local master is up-to-date with the remote master?

Comment: I make a habit of running `git remote update` periodically, and using `git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate` to get a sense of how up-to-date my local repository is compared to the remote(s).

Comment: @chepner but `git remote update` doesn't merge any changes?

Comment: No, it just transfers commits from the remote that you don't have in your remote tracking branches. This lets you easily see the difference between, say, `master` and `origin/master`.

Comment: Things like `git status` that can report on whether your local branch is up-to-date or behind/ahead a remote aren't communicating directly with the remote; that would defeat the purpose of Git being a distributed VCS. Instead, your repository contains a *copy* of the remote so that all actions are local. The only communication occurs when you use `git fetch` (used by `git remote update`) to pull new commits down, or `git push` to push new commits up.

Comment: @chepner as I wrote in my question (and I thought this was clear), I'm the only one coding on this project, I can't push to master, and I push always to dev. In other words, I can only create PR's to merge dev into master. So why master would have conflict is honestly beyond me. (All the conflicts were things I had changed in dev, we're under staffed thanks to the current hysteria, so I did not want to see where the fault was. If my tests pass in dev, they pass in master. That's all that matters.)

Comment: Did you actually do as I suggest to confirm that your repository is in the state you claim? Just because you think something can't possibly happen doesn't mean it hasn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to backup first!

> How can I override this and force master to take all the changes from dev?

You can reset top of your master branch to dev.

```
# goto local master
git checkout master

# reset local master to local dev
git reset dev
# _or_ reset local master to remote dev
#git fetch --all
#git reset origin/dev

# and push local master to remote master
git push --force-with-lease   # or --force
```

Comment: Thank you! `git reset dev` worked fine. I had to unlock my master branch in order to force push, but it was a sacrifice I was willing to make :)